# ARCH grub-mkconfig doesn't do anything

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, grub2-mkconfig

i tried installing ARCH and everything seems to work pretty fine.
I followed this installation for the most part (https://gitlab.com/jsherman82/notes/blob/master/arch.md)

But i seem to have a problem with the installtion of the bootloader and its configuration.

My System has three partitions:

```
nvme0n1p1 with 400MiB of type EFI System mounted at /boot/EFI
nvme0n1p2 with 400MiB of type ext2 mounted at /boot
nvme0n1p3 with the rest of the disk (~240GiB) of type lvm
```

`nvme0n1p3` is encrypted via cryptsetup and split into two lvm-partitions:

```
main-root with 30GiB mounted at /
main-home with the rest mounted at /home
```

So far so good.

I edited this line of `/etc/default/grub` to read like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cryptdevice=/dev/nvme0n1p3:main quiet"
```

But when I did Step 38) `# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` nothing happens. There is no output and the terminal is stuck with a blinking cursor. I have to manually stop the program via `^C`.
I tried the same command without writing to a file - just a blinking coursor.

`/boot/grub` does not have a `grub.cfg`-file in it (obviously).

I need to solve this problem  and generate a `grub.cfg`-File.

Comment: There is a problem with encryption! Have you read this https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Encrypted_/boot ?